# How is it possible that node.js creates 2 instances of singleton class?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-sent-events

**Setup:** typescript 4.9.4, next.js 13.0.6

**What I’m trying to do:** messenger app. Messaging system based in Server-sent events (SSE), not WS

**What’s the idea:** incoming messages are handled by SSE endpoint: https://github.com/sincerely-manny/messenger.nextjs/blob/main/pages/api/messenger/incoming.ts

outgoing messages are being accepted as POST-requests here: https://github.com/sincerely-manny/messenger.nextjs/blob/main/pages/api/messenger/outgoing.ts

Singleton-class is collecting list of clients/connections and response-objects: https://github.com/sincerely-manny/messenger.nextjs/blob/main/lib/sse/serverSentEvents.ts

Whenever anyone needs to send a message he is to grab the instance of SSE class and trigger the "send" method.

Front-end part: https://github.com/sincerely-manny/messenger.nextjs/blob/main/app/messenger/page.tsx

**Expected behaviour:** upon establishing first connection instance of SSE class is created. Then every call of the send method finds corresponding to the client response object and and puts message to the stream

**Actual behaviour:** upon connecting to sse endpoint instance (1) of the class is created. Client is registered in list. But (!) sending a message creates another (2) instance of singleton-class with empty clients list. Hence sent message is lost. But (!!) after refreshing the page and creating new connection app takes this second (2) instance, puts client there and everything starts working as expected.

**The question:** how’s that possible and what should I do to avoid this unwanted behaviour.

**Update:** turns out the problem persists only in dev mode, while compiling pages on-the-fly. That makes it easier, but doesn’t explain why it happens.

Comment: How do you know that these are difference instances?

Comment: constructor generates random id and "send" method console.logs it on every triggering. This way I can see which instance is being used

Comment: If you add a console log [here](https://github.com/sincerely-manny/messenger.nextjs/blob/main/lib/sse/serverSentEvents.ts#L38) would it print two times?

Comment: Yep. https://ibb.co/jVLGmWF

Comment: There is a compilation between them. It seems that your app crashed and started again

Comment: hmmmm… nope, don’t think so. Next just compiles pages on-demand. But I’ll double-check that

Comment: It's not just two instances. From your logs you ran 3 different servers. Your first message was sent by the 1st server. Then you edited the `/_error` file and your framework shuts down the server that sent that 1st message - therefore whatever variables you saved, whatever arrays you have created got deleted because the server quit. Then your framework starts up a 2nd server (it's like quitting notepad.exe and launching it again - whatever you didn't save to disk is lost). Then you edited the file `/api/messenger/outgoing` and...

Comment: ... your framework kills the 2nd server thereby deleting all variables in RAM. Then it starts a 3rd server which sends the 2nd message. It's not that you have two instances of the singleton - all 3 servers have only **ONE** instance of the singleton. It's that your framework killed your server and restarted it so you have 3 different singletons!

Comment: This is why in general people use databases in backend code. Newbies who have no experience with web programming sometimes think databases are overkill when you can just save the state in an array in a variable.. however you cannot predict when your server will be killed or restarted. In this case your server is restarted by your framework because it has a development mode that updates the code as you edit them. In the real world you never know when a sysadmin (who may or may not be you) will restart the server for one reason or another.

Comment: oh, thank you @slebetman. That pretty much explains it. Probably idea to store clients in db is a good one. Still can't figure out how to store non-serializable responses